# How can I run simultaneously two different firefox profiles

Tags: firefox

In (K)ubuntu, how can I run more than one Firefox profile simultaneously? I need this to run different websites with different extensions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use different profiles. Start Firefox as

```
firefox -ProfileManager -no-remote
```

to get the profile manager.

Comment: I use this method, have done for some time. Works well.