# How to create shortcuts to different Firefox profiles

Tags: firefox

I followed the instructions present [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84899/how-can-i-run-simultaneously-two-different-firefox-profiles) in order to use two Firefox profiles simultaneously. But I would like to make this process faster by starting each profile from its own shortcut. How do I create a shortcut to launch each profile?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use your menu launcher creator (or right click the desktop and select new launcher, depending on what desktop you are on) to fashion two new `firefox` launchers. The command you need for each launcher is, for example:

```
firefox -Profile /home/mike/.mozilla/firefox/55divdmr.Mike2 -no-remote
```

This will launch `firefox` with that profile and make sure that it doesn't connect to any other running instance of `firefox` with the essential `-no-remote` switch.

If you wanted to do it manually, the desktop shortcut would look something like this; you could create it in a text-editor and name it `firefox2.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=fox2
Comment=my second profile
Exec=firefox -Profile /home/mike/.mozilla/firefox/55divdmr.Mike2 -no-remote
Path=/home/mike
Icon=/my/icon/location
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
```

---

Something else I recommend is going to your firefox folder ( mine is `/home/mike/.mozilla/firefox`) and checking that the `StartWithLastProfile` setting in `profiles.ini` is false:

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=0
```

This is because it can get confusing if you are using different profiles and you start `firefox` as normal without using a special shortcut and it just loads the last profile used.

You can also get prompted each time for which profile to use by making sure 'don't ask at startup' is unchecked, which is in the firefox `ProfileManager` settings below. This setting is reached with

```
firefox -ProfileManager -no-remote
```

as noted in [the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84899/how-can-i-run-simultaneously-two-different-firefox-profiles) you referred to.

[image]

For more information on the command switches available for `firefox` see `man firefox` or the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/firefox.1.html). Further support is available at [mozilla.org](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/home).

Answer (score 3):

I find this works:

1. Open file explorer
2. Navigate to `/usr/share/applications`
3. Right-click on the Firefox link and select copy
4. Click on your desktop and select paste
5. Right click on the icon that has just been created and select properties
6. On the Basic tab fill command: `firefox -no-remote -P "profile name"`
7. On the Permissions tab check Execute

[image: ScreenShot]

Done!

Comment: Simple and good

Comment: Can't find Firefox in that folder

Comment: For me the path was /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop