# Installing multiple version of chrome & firefox on one ubuntu machine

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

i would like to install many chrome and firefox versions for one user in ubuntu. if it is possible, how can i do it?

thanks.

Comment: Related: [This older post](http://askubuntu.com/q/226335/37165) gives a hint on how to use Firefox profile manager to run multiple profiles for the multiple version of Firefox, if any.

Answer (score 3):

If you download firefox from Mozilla's page you don't get a deb package, you get a folder with an executable in it. You can have as many as you want of those.

If you don't want you configuration files to clash, simply use different home folders for different versions. For example, if you downloaded firefox, extracted it and renamed the folder to "firefox2" in your home folder, do the following:

```
cd firefox2
export HOME=$(pwd)      #sets current folder as your home for all programs invoked from this terminal or script
./firefox --no-remote   #without "no-remote" firefox creates a new window for active firefox session
```

Notice that linux created a ".mozilla" folder in your firefox2 folder. You can have as many versions as you like and even run them at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer

You can't.

#### Long Answer

Download the compressed browser package, extract it and locate the launcher.
Copy the package over the different `/home` directories.

Firefox packages: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/1.0/contrib/
Chrome: Can't find any - Google doesn't seem to officially support compressed packages of its browser.