# How to run firefox as two instances with two icons in Ubuntu

Tags: firefox, .desktop

I want to run `firefox` as two instances or applications, with each running a different website with two different application icons. I tried `firefox -no-remote` but it returns an error as a pop-up :

[image]

Does anyone know how to get over with this? I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84899/how-can-i-run-simultaneously-two-different-firefox-profiles) question, but did not work out.

Comment: It's extreme but have you tried installing firefox from snap along side of firefox from apt? Also extreme, what youre describing works just fine on my computer, I am using metacity(flashback) desktop.... I'm sure MATE would work just as easy, being they both have a panel and configurable launchers.... and even more extreme .Appimage, but the firefox .Appimage is not supported, so you probably dont want that

Comment: how about a standalone firefox ... or run a torproject.org torified firefox, not recommended to run at the same time with the default firefox app b ut that might only be a security thing.    https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable

Comment: @pierrely Let me check

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new desktop shortcut, eg. new `.desktop` file. So let say that you have:

```bsh
firefox2.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
.....
Exec= firefox -no-remote -P ProfileName

Icon=path/to/your/special/icon/or/com/location/
```

Also if you drop ProfileName you would get menu for creating new profile, or selecting old one.

Next step will be configuring taskbar, for example if you are using KDE Plasma, you can configure taskbar/icon-only taskbar to group of ungroup icons. For exact instructions you need to provide exact name of your DE and taskbar you are using(built-in , extension etc.) So icon on the desktop would be different, but taskbar icon will be the same(default or icon-theme based) but ungrouped.
For better answer(and if this is not your desired result), please provide which DE and taskbar are you using.
P.S. You got that error because you opened new Firefox instance with the same profile.

EDIT:
**GNOME 3.18 - 3.38**
You can use extension called [Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/), it is very easy to configure it via Gnome Tweaks (you can install it  via  `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions`).

**KDE PLASMA**
For task manager you are probably using task manager extension or icon-only task manager, both of them con be configured via righ-click -> Configure  -> Behaviour-> group.

Comment: I am using the buit-in task bar

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but is still grouped, can you please post how to un-group the icons.

Comment: So you are using buil-in on Gnome, KDE Plasma, Mate... ?

Comment: Yes, I am using the build-in Gnome one

Comment: Then you can not, only way is to use some extension, like Dash to Panel. You can configured it as you wish (even to look like built-in one). If you need help, feel free to ask. There was extension named TaskBar (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/584/taskbar/), but it can only be used with older version, since its development stopped in December of 2019.